Can I retrieve workspace GUIDs from cm?
I am writing a Python wrapper for Plastic/UVCS so my team can integrate it more smoothly into our content pipeline. I would like a workspace to have an object that represents it in my Python code. Is there any way to fetch the GUID of a workspace from cm? I know I can use cm find for several other types of key information, and I know that the GUIDs are stored in the plastic4 directory. Please let me know if I might get this info using cm. Thank you!
I have tried cm wk, cm status, cm ss, and I have looked through the docs for cm find a bit to see if there's a field for workspace, but I haven't been able to find anything.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You should be able to use the following command:
cm workspace list --format={3}


Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!
